# Conditional join with CASE statement causes syntax error

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I essentially want to write a conditional join below where I have the `CASE` statement, however this is resulting in syntax error. I basically want to only use this join if the `OWNING_ENTITY_ID` equals the `ORGANIZATION_ID`, otherwise if they do not match then I do not want to join on this.

```
   SELECT cce.*
   FROM INV_TRANSACTIONS cce, SYSTEM_ITEMS DEF

   WHERE cce.LOCATOR_ID = DEF.LOCATOR_ID
    AND CASE WHEN cce.OWNING_ENTITY_ID = cce.ORGANIZATION_ID
             THEN cce.OWNING_ENTITY_ID = cce.ORGANIZATION_ID 
             END
```

Comment: In general it's better to use regular AND/OR constructions instead of case _expressions_ in a WHERE or ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

Your case statement should return the value and that returned value should be compared with organization_id

```
SELECT cce.* 
FROM INV_TRANSACTIONS cce
JOIN SYSTEM_ITEMS DEF ON cce.LOCATOR_ID = 
DEF.LOCATOR_ID AND CASE WHEN cce.OWNING_ENTITY_ID = cce.ORGANIZATION_ID THEN   
     cce.OWNING_ENTITY_ID END 
= cce.ORGANIZATION_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

> only use this join if the `OWNING_ENTITY_ID` equals the `ORGANIZATION_ID`, otherwise if they do not match then I do not want to join on this.

The easiest way to implement that logic is to not implement it as you do not care if they don't match.

Which would simplify the statement to:

```sql
SELECT cce.*
FROM   INV_TRANSACTIONS cce
       INNER JOIN SYSTEM_ITEMS DEF
       ON cce.LOCATOR_ID = DEF.LOCATOR_ID
```

But you could also implement it as:

```sql
SELECT cce.*
FROM   INV_TRANSACTIONS cce
       INNER JOIN SYSTEM_ITEMS DEF
       ON  cce.LOCATOR_ID = DEF.LOCATOR_ID
WHERE  cce.OWNING_ENTITY_ID =  cce.ORGANIZATION_ID
OR     1 = 1;
```

(But `1 = 1` would match every row, so you may as well omit the `WHERE` clause.)